# Python: How to access returned values to put into a table?

Tags: python, indexing, max, minimum

*Note: I am a very beginner in Python so please bear with me!*

*edit: I have fixed the error but I need help with my question down below!*

**My question is:**

1) If I want to put the minimum value(s) and most common word/number onto a table, how can I index to the minimum value/most common word and extract it and place it in the correct position on my table?

**Description**

The following code is supposed to transpose the given nested list, A, using the function

`def rows2cols(A):`,

then run through that list and for every column I check to see if it has numeric values or not using

`def isnumericlist(A):`.

If the list does have numeric values, I convert the strings to floats and find the minimum value and most common word/number from that list.

The code is the following:

```
A = [['OrderDate', 'Region', 'Rep', 'Item', 'Units', 'Unit Price'],['4-Jul-2014', 'East', 'Richard', 'Pen Set', '62', '4.99'], ['12-Jul-2014', 'East', 'Nick', 'Binder', '29', '1.99'], ['21-Jul-2014', 'Central', 'Morgan', 'Pen Set', '55', '12.49'], ['29-Jul-2014', 'East', 'Susan', 'Binder', '81', '19.99'],['7-Aug-2014', 'Central', 'Matthew', 'Pen Set', '42', '23.95'], ['15-Aug-2014', 'East', 'Richard', 'Pencil', '35', '4.99'], ['24-Aug-2014', 'West', 'James', 'Desk', '3', '275']]

minVal = []
maxVal = []
hist = []
average = []
stanDev = []
headers = A[0] #this sets the variable "headers" as the first row 
rows = A[1:] #skips the first row

def rows2cols(A):
    if len(A) == 0: 
        return []                      #this covers the base case of having an empty csv file
    res  = [[] for x in headers]       # would create a list of empty lists
    for line in A: 
        for col in range(len(line)): 
            res[col].append(line[col]) 
    return res

def convertstringtofloats(A):
    res = []
    for x in A:
        res.append(float(x))
    return res

def isnumericlist(A):
    for x in A:
        try:
            numeric = float(x) 
        except:
            return False
    return True


def getMin(A):
    res = B[0] #first column AFTER you transpose the nested list
    for x in A:
        if x < res:
            res = x
    return res

def most_common(A):
    counts = {}
    for x in A:
        counts[tuple(x)] = counts.get(tuple(x), 0) + 1 
    max = -1
    maxKey = ""
    for key,value in counts.items():
        if max < value:
            max = value
            maxKey = key
    return maxKey

def notnumeric(A):
    return "n/a"

cols = rows2cols(rows)

for col in range(len(headers)):
    if isnumericlist(cols[col]):
        B = convertstringtofloats(cols[col])
        minVal.append(getMin(B))
        maxVal.append(getMax(B))
        average.append(getAvg(B))
        stanDev.append(getSD(B))
    else:
        notnumeric(col)

    mode.append(most_common(cols[col]))

tablevalues = [minVal, maxVal, average, stanDev, mode]
```

**My code for producing a table is below, along with a sample table as to how I would like the outcome to be!**

```
def print_table(table):
    longest_cols = [
        (max([len(str(row[i])) for row in table]) + 0) for i in range(len(table[0]))
    ]
    row_format = "|".join([" {:>" + str(longest_col) + "} " for longest_col in longest_cols])
    first = True
    for row in table:
        print(row_format.format(*row))
        if first:
            print((sum(longest_cols) + (len(table[0]) - 0) * 3) * "-")
            first = False

table = [
    ["Columns:", "Min", "Max", "Avg", "Std. Dev.", "Most Common Word"],
    ["OrderDate", "n/a", "n/a", "n/a", "n/a", "John"],
    ["Region", 3.3, 6.29, 4.888, 1.333, 4.911],
    ["Rep", 1.3, 3.2, 1.888, 0.333, 1.9],
    ["Item", 1.3, 3.2, 1.888, 0.333, 1.9],
    ["Units","n/a", "n/a", "n/a", "n/a", "John"],
    ["Unit Price","n/a", "n/a", "n/a", "n/a", "John"]
]
print_table(table)
```

Comment: Can your break down your problem into which line is giving the error? Do you expect the readers to first read your whole code and then find out line by line where the error might be coming from? Also, `most_common(cols)` just calls the function but your are not storing the returned value in any variable

Comment: It's not obvious to me where your error is occurring. Can you edit the question to include the full traceback of your exception? You've

Comment: @Bazingaa, @Blckknght; Sorry! I created this question while trying to fix my error and ended up fixing it on my own. I just need help with my question below the code.

Comment: @Bazingaa How do I store the returned value? Also, when I put my code into the PythonTutor website, the "most_common(cols)" doesn't go through each element in each cols. It seems to skip over each list until it gets to the list with numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Pandas might be of help to you. `df.describe(include='all')` will rovide you with the table you need. you just need to read your data A using pandas and change data types in each column according to your need. `top` is the most common word in the respective column and `freq` is times of occurrence of this particular word. you even can save this table as a new dataframe as `df2 = df.describe(include='all')`

```
import pandas as pd
A = [['OrderDate', 'Region', 'Rep', 'Item', 'Units', 'Unit Price'],
     ['4-Jul-2014', 'East', 'Richard', 'Pen Set', '62', '4.99'], 
     ['12-Jul-2014', 'East', 'Nick', 'Binder', '29', '1.99'], 
     ['21-Jul-2014', 'Central', 'Morgan', 'Pen Set', '55', '12.49'], 
     ['29-Jul-2014', 'East', 'Susan', 'Binder', '81', '19.99'],
     ['7-Aug-2014', 'Central', 'Matthew', 'Pen Set', '42', '23.95'], 
     ['15-Aug-2014', 'East', 'Richard', 'Pencil', '35', '4.99'], 
     ['24-Aug-2014', 'West', 'James', 'Desk', '3', '275']]

df = pd.DataFrame(A[1:],columns=A[0])

print(df)

OrderDate   Region  Rep Item    Units   Unit Price
0   04-Jul-2014 East    Richard Pen Set 62  4.99
1   12-Jul-2014 East    Nick    Binder  29  1.99
2   21-Jul-2014 Central Morgan  Pen Set 55  12.49
3   29-Jul-2014 East    Susan   Binder  81  19.99
4   07-Aug-2014 Central Matthew Pen Set 42  23.95
5   15-Aug-2014 East    Richard Pencil  35  4.99
6   24-Aug-2014 West    James   Desk    3   275.00

df = df.astype(dtype={'OrderDate':'str', 'Region':'str',
     'Rep':'str', 'Item':'str', 'Units':'int', 'Unit Price':'float'})

df['OrderDate'] = df.OrderDate.apply(
    lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%d-%b-%Y'))

print(df.dtypes)
OrderDate      object
Region         object
Rep            object
Item           object
Units           int32
Unit Price    float64
dtype: object

print(df.describe(include='all'))

OrderDate   Region  Rep Item    Units   Unit Price
count   7   7   7   7   7.000000    7.000000
unique  7   3   6   4   NaN NaN
top     24-Aug-2014 East    Richard Pen Set NaN NaN
freq    1   4   2   3   NaN         NaN
mean    NaN NaN NaN NaN 43.857143   49.057143
std     NaN NaN NaN NaN 25.182193   99.968112
min     NaN NaN NaN NaN 3.000000    1.990000
25%     NaN NaN NaN NaN 32.000000   4.990000
50%     NaN NaN NaN NaN 42.000000   12.490000
75%     NaN NaN NaN NaN 58.500000   21.970000
max     NaN NaN NaN NaN 81.000000   275.000000
```

Comment: Could you provide a solution as to how to do this without Pandas? The only imports I am allowed to use are "csv" and "matplotlib.pyplot". Thanks for the input though!

Comment: @K.Wong it is doable but cumbersome and time inefficient with nested for loops. you need at least numpy if not pandas. However, the later is highly recommended for financial and econometric analysis. Sorry if the answer was not of help.